# I want to set the class value by click on the button

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to set the class value by click on the button

-if click onPlus it will have a string value = @"+"
 -if click onMinus it will have a string value = @"-"

here's the code

```
for(Tile *s in player){ //player is a NSMutableArray


//(bla bla bla)

plusBtn = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"plus.png" 
selectedImage:@"plus.png" target:self selector:@selector(onPlus:)];

minusBTn = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"minus.png" selectedImage:@"minus.png" 
target:self selector:@selector(onMinus:)];

//(bla bla bla)

}

 -(void)onPlus:(Tile *) s
{
 s.setValue = @"+";
}

 -(void)onMinus:(Tile *) s
{
 s.setValue = @"-";
}
```

How to set it???

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here ? what do you want to set ? the class of what ?

Comment: Please specify what you want clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The argument sent to your onPlus or onMinus methods will not be the tile, but the button itself. You will need to work out which tile the button was in. I can't advise on that except to say `bla bla bla` ;)